# Running node.js and elasticsearch together

Tags: node.js, macos, elasticsearch

I've today first used node.js and it's running on `localhost:888` i've also installed elasticsearch to `localhost:9200`. When I start them from the terminal they start fine, but when I start one the other stops. This is on Mac OSX, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What commands are you using to start them? Are you starting them from the same Terminal session? Try using separate tabs (⌘T) or windows (⌘N).

Comment: I was yes, I've never used a Mac before, I shall try this

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Seems to work now, add this as answer and i'll accept it. I also noted that when I close the terminal that the servers stop. I'm guessing that is the right behaviour?